# NSNotifications between applications in OS X

Tags: cocoa, pyobjc, nsnotification

I have a working App that sends an NSNotification to itself when the User pushes a button in the window (Xcode using PyObjC):

```
from Foundation import *
from AppKit import *
import objc

class SpeakAppDelegate(NSObject):
    def applicationDidFinishLaunching_(self, sender):
        NSLog("Application really did finish launching.")
        nc = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
        nc.addObserver_selector_name_object_(
            self, "mycallback:", 'love_note', None)
            #self, "mycallback:", None, None)

    @objc.signature('v@0:@8')
    def mycallback_(self,note):
        print 'note'
        print note.description()

    @objc.IBAction
    def button_(self,sender):
        print sender, 'button'
        nc = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
        nc.postNotificationName_object_userInfo_(
            'love_note', None, {'path':'xyz'})
```

(A detail:  the signature is probably not exactly right, but it works).

Leave it running.  Now I want to figure out how to send the same notification to this App from another application, for example:

```
// gcc tell.m -o test -framework Foundation
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main() {
    NSNotificationCenter *nc;
    nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc postNotificationName:@"love_note"
                      object:nil
                    userInfo:nil ];
    return 0;
}
```

I notice that if I un-comment the line in the first App then I get lots of other notifications, but they are all from events related to my App.  I never hear anything from outside.  How can I send a notification between processes?  And then, is there any way to send a notification from the command line?  Thanks.

Update:  Simply substitute NSDistributedNotificationCenter above, and the example works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to do communication between two apps using NSNotificationCenter. I have not used it before, but I believe two apps communicating is more of a job for [Distributed Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DistrObjects/DistrObjects.html).

From Apple's documentation:

> Each process has a default
>   notification center that you access
>   with the NSNotificationCenter
>   +defaultCenter class method. This notification center handles
>   notifications within a single process.
>   For communication between processes on
>   the same machine, use a distributed
>   notification center (see
>   “NSDistributedNotificationCenter”).

**EDIT**:

It does seem like [NSDistributedNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDistributedNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDistributedNotificationCenter) could also do what you are looking for without getting deep into Distributed Objects.

Comment: Thanks.  The distinction between the two types of Centers had escaped me.

Comment: It really depends on the type of the notification. For example iTunes sends notifications whenever it starts/stops playing a song. You can write an application that listens to those notifications. If your goal is more to have a remote, then some sort of direct communications (e.g. through distributed objects) is more appropriate.

Comment: +1 for distributed notifications. they're not secure, but for basic communication they're pretty brain-dead simple.

Comment: Note the caveats in the NSDistributedNotificationCenter docs: "Posting a distributed notification is an expensive operation. The notification gets sent to a system-wide server that distributes it to all the tasks that have objects registered for distributed notifications. The latency between posting the notification and the notification’s arrival in another task is unbounded. In fact, when too many notifications are posted and the server’s queue fills up, notifications may be dropped". Generally speaking it's not safe to use it for messages your app relies on to work.